# Бывают ли книги по программированию в формате fb2 или epub?

Tags: книги, fb2, epub, форматы-файлов

Обратил внимание, что все книги по программированию у меня в формате `.pdf`.
А ридер всего 6 дюймов, читать код не очень удобно. Поискал в сети книги с кодом в формате `.epub/.fb2`. Чуть-чуть нашёл. Но у них одна особенность: там почти начисто отсутствует `кодовая разметка`.

**Вопрос**: Можно ли в принципе запихнуть `кодовую разметку` в файл `fb2/epub`? Хочу понять, если смысл искать книги по программированию в таком формате.

Comment: Специальная разметка в этих форматах есть (тег code), но, увы, ее редко используют. Задавался такими же вопросами, тоже искал книги по программированию в этих форматах для читалок. К сожалению, приходится юзать pdf на нормальном компе с большим экраном. А в epub/fb2/mobi - только книги по "теории" и на околокомпьютерные темы.

Comment: на gitbook.com масса книг, которые можно скачать в epub. Разметка присутствует. Например https://legacy.gitbook.com/book/maxfarseer/react-course-ru/details. В списке download выбираете epub

Comment: Собственно разметка зависит от желания авторов сделать разметку кода. Если издательству предоставлены текст с картинками, то скорей всего в издательстве никто перебирать не будет

Comment: fb2 это xml, так что при желании проблем с форматированным кодом нет (только его надо переформатировать под размер окна)